# Better query to delete object inside a collection

Tags: collection, collection-filtering

I'm trying to delete a wishlist item from the collection, the code works, but whats a better way instead of using the naive forloop

```
       $wishlist_collection = Mage::getModel('wishlist/item')->getCollection()
->addCustomerIdFilter($customer->getId());

        // @note come on, find better way
        foreach($wishlist_collection as $wish) {
            if ($wish->getProductId() == $product_id) 
                $wish->delete();
        }
```

Comment: try $wish->_getResource()->delete()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to exclude an item based on it's id. For this, you can try below code

```
$wishlist_collection = Mage::getModel('wishlist/item')->getCollection()
                            ->addCustomerIdFilter($customer->getId())
                            ->addFieldToFilter('id', array('neq' => $product_id))
                            ->load();

// @note come on, we got a better way :)
foreach ($wishlist_collection as $wish) {
    echo $wish->getId();
}
```

As you can see `addFieldToFilter('id', array('neq' => $product_id))` will do the job for you. This is the proper way to do this job.

Comment: right, but product_id instead of id, and eq instead of neq

Comment: Happy to help you